# Templated object doesn't create new visual representation just because it's of the same type as the previous object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

If I have a DataTemplate for a certain data type and I change the DataContext of a ContentPresenter to an object of different type, the DataTemplate of the second type gets evaluated, new controls are built and so on – everything works as expected (or at least as I expected). Now if the new data object has the same type, it doesn't get reevaluated, the controls somehow get reused, they're not unloaded, and they even maintain state. A ScrollViewer for example "remembers" how far the content was scrolled and so on. This behaviour seems pretty unstable to me and goes against everything what I've learned about WPF, data binding and MVVM in the last months. If the data changes, the presentation should change accordingly and in the same way regardless of the type.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have a misconception about templates or data binding? Is this how it's supposed to behave? And most importantly: how do I prevent this? I can't really see me binding every possible property of a control to a view model, just to get it "like new".

Setting the DataContext to null just before assigning the new object doesn't work either, only if it's like a solid intermediate step. (???)

Below is some code that illustrates what seems so weird to me:

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplateReuseOrNot.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplateReuseOrNot"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
        <ScrollViewer Height="300">
            <Border Background="HotPink" Height="2000">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <RadioButton></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton></RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
        <ScrollViewer Height="300" >
            <Border Background="Yellow" Height="2000">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <RadioButton></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton></RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"></ContentPresenter>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="NewViewModelA">DataContext = New ViewModelA</Button>
        <Button Click="NewViewModelB">DataContext = New ViewModelB</Button>
        <Button Click="ViewModelNull">DataContext = null</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DataTemplateReuseOrNot
    {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NewViewModelA(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            this.DataContext = new ViewModelA();
        }

        private void NewViewModelB(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataContext = new ViewModelB();
        }

        private void ViewModelNull(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            this.DataContext = null;
        }
    }

    public class ViewModelA
    {
    }

    public class ViewModelB
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said `I have a DataTemplate for a certain data type`, it seems pretty straightforward that only the **type** of your datacontext is relevant for determining, whether a redraw has to happen or not.

For a comparison take a look at the standard implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a viewmodel's properties:

```
set {
   if (value != this.backingField) {
      this.backingField = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

If you overwrite a property containing "hello world" with "hello world" nothing will happen. In your case, you're overwriting ViewModelA with ViewModelA, so nothing will happen. Here the type is the data.

If you need a redraw after changing from "ViewModelA" to another "ViewModelA", you might want to give `InvalidateVisual` a try.

Comment: Your comparison has a flaw: value != backingField is going to be true as long as it is different objects. Even if I consider loaded templates to be representative for a whole type instead of just an instance, it conflicts with the result you're getting when you're switching between different types, because then it "forgets". And even if a type would be templated just once and reused forever, I *still* would be asking how to get a new visual representation. I'll give InvalidateVisual a deeper look, but "This method is not generally called from your application code" doesn't actually sound good.

Comment: "Invalidates the rendering of the element, and forces a complete new layout pass." doesn't sound promising either. I don't have a problem with the rendering, and I'm pretty sure there's rendering necessary to actually see the new bound data. I can't shake the feeling that I'm applying MVVM wrong in some way.

Comment: You're right regarding the flaw when looking at complex objects. You're not, when looking at the string example. And in your case - after setting the DataContext to instance1 of ViewModelA - `backingField` (of type `Type`) would contain `instance1.GetType()`. When you switch to instance2 of ViewModelA, the comparison would be resolved as equal.

With `InvalidateVisual` I just wanted to show a way, if you need rerendering, which can't be accomplished by another instance. If you can avoid to use it, avoid it.